Unable to Set Private Member in Google Test TEST_F Function Despite Friend Class Declaration
I can successfully set and access privateData in the SetUp() method, but when I try to do the same in a TEST_F function, the code doesn't compile, and it tells me that the function is unaccessible.
I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm accessing or modifying the private member from the test cases, but given the setup, it should be permissible due to the friend class declaration.
Question:
What could be causing this inability to set the private member from within the TEST_F functions? Is there a mistake in how I've set up the test fixture or in my understanding of the friend class mechanism in C++?
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A {
    friend class testsA;  // Friend class declaration

private:
    int privateData;

public:
    A() : privateData(0) {}
private:
    void setPrivateData(int data) { privateData = data; }
    int getPrivateData() const { return privateData; }
};

#endif // A_H

#ifndef TESTS_A_H
#define TESTS_A_H

#include "A.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class testsA : public testing::Test {
public:
    A* a_instance;  // Public member instance of A
    
protected:
    void SetUp() override {
        a_instance = new A();
        a_instance->setPrivateData(42);  // Set private member in SetUp
    }
};

#endif // TESTS_A_H

#include "testsA.h"

TEST_F(testsA, TestPrivateDataSetting) {
    // Trying to access and set private data in the test case
    a_instance->setPrivateData(100);
    ASSERT_EQ(a_instance->getPrivateData(), 100);
}

TEST_F(testsA, EnsureSetUpValueAccessible) {
    // This will access the value set in SetUp
    ASSERT_EQ(a_instance->getPrivateData(), 42);
}


If privacy was an issue then you would get a compile error. If a value is not being set when you run your program that is because your program has a bug. These are two completely separate issues.

Offtopic: IMHO testing private parts of code is bad practice. This means that you are testing implementation detail. As a result test constrains you and blocks you from doing refactorings.

It didn't compile, I'll edit the question. because the member is unaccesible.

Can't repro with code provided: https://godbolt.org/z/6rP5rWYbj

@Sam12 I see no compilation issue with the posted code, setPrivateData and getPrivateData are both public functions in the code above, therefore there is no need for friendship.

When using TEST_F in google test, the test function is a subclass of your Fixture class.  In C++, friend classes do not extend to descendant classes of your friend.  So while TestA is a friend, the classes created by the TEST_F macro are not.

For completeness, you could add the link to doc: https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#testing-private-code and mention FRIEND_TEST macro.

But in the posted code, both functions and the instance variable are public. No friendship is necessary.

@John, they're private. I changed the code due to company's privacy. I edited it.

@Yksisarvinen
There's alot of tests which use these methods. what is the best practice to do it?
